# Sublime text keymap launching "extension"

Tags: python, text, editor, sublimetext2

Basically I'm using Sublime Text 2 to edit and (hopefully) run Python files. At the minute though, to run a file, I'm having to tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, type at least two letters (P, Y) and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>. Then the script runs. I want to assign this to a hotkey. I therefor ventured into the world of sublime-keymap files, and nearly died of boredom.

A sample command:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+v"], "command": "paste" },
```

My attempt:

```
{ "keys": ["f5"], "command": "SublimeREPL: Python - RUN current file" },
```

Could someone please inform me of what mistake it is that I'm making?
How can I go about not making that mistake?

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I think you might be interested in Sublime's [build systems](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html?highlight=build). Did you try f7 or ctrl+b on your python file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the build system, as morphyn suggested, but I'll address the issue of using SublimeRepl (and key bindings). The command you want isn't the text from the command palette, but the command actually running. After a quick look through the plugin, I tracked down the commands file [here](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Python/Default.sublime-commands). This file specifies what will be shown in the command palette, and what will be run when selected. For your specific case, you will want to create the following in your User defined key maps (accessible through `Preferences -> Key Bindings - User`, but I think you found that already).

```
{
    "keys": ["f5"],
    "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
    {
        "id": "repl_python_run",
        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
    }
}
```

I haven't run it myself, but that should work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That looks to be pretty much what I'm after. Ill give it a shot in half hour or so (nearly at work now!) I'm actually using the build system already but the problem with it is it just creates a .pyc, doesn't run it, not sure how to change that but using this addon if I just save then hit F5 it will run using CMD, so I can test my script as I want without having to manually launch it...

Comment: Brilliant, it works! Just out of interest, do you know how to link a hotkey to a batch file on ST2? One chunk of our test suite is mapped in a strange way and has a large structure consisting of multiple files, so would be immensely useful if I could press maybe F7, and have it automatically run a file which isn't the current loaded .py file, but a .py file in the file system, 1 level up.

Comment: @XtrmJosh
Suppose you could write your own small plugin to run the script, then bind that command to F7. Not the greatest way to go about it, but it should work. Is the file that isn't loaded always the same between runs? I'm sure you can't give me all the information about your system since it's work, but I'd be happy to try to stub something out if you want. Let me know.